# How does one find this site?

Tags: discussion

The only time I have ever seen this "Aviation Meta" SE is when a question in "Aviation" has been migrated.  What if I want to ask something in meta?  I don't see it in the list of all SE sites, or a link from Aviation.  Is there a secret moderator trick to get here?

Comment: Both answers are correct, which one do I accept?!  ;)

Comment: Accepting an answer indicates that you, the OP, found it to be the most useful to you.  A quirk of the SE system is that this doesn't necessarily mean that it is correct.  Equally, you don't have to accept either.

Answer (score 7):

You can access Meta via the question mark icon at the top of the page:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

All "Meta" sites are shown beneath the main site in the navigation dropdown. This is not moderator thing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to just bookmark it, or do it the way I do and type the URL. The main site is the site starting with "a" that I use most, so I just type "a" and Firefox autofills it. To get here, I type "aviation.m", then it autofills.

Every SE site has one of these "meta" sites; just put ".meta" before "stackexchange.com"; e.g. [Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com)'s meta site is https://law.meta.stackexchange.com. There's a network-wide Meta too; it's at https://meta.stackexchange.com. For sites like [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) and [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com) that don't have SE domains, just put "meta." before the domain, e.g. https://meta.askubuntu.com.